# Oracle SQL - creating a loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a script that shows delivery qty data for several manufacturing components. Each component has a different new release date so data will run from a different start date (earliest date is 01/07/2007).

Full script is posted below. The script that I would like to add is ...

*** SCRIPT REMOVED ***

... this shows the sum of the delivered qty from new release date for a 91 day period (3 months). I could repeat this sub select for each 3 month period but, I would have to add more sub selects as time goes on to keep data running to date.

Is there a way to run a loop so to return the delivered qty every 91 days from the new release to date?

*** SCRIPT REMOVED ***

---

OK ... thanks for all your advice re: JOIN's and subqueries.

I have revised the JOINS in the script and removed many of the subqueries (full script below).

My question now goes back to the creation of a loop in SQL. Instead of creating dozens of subqueries to show the delivery qty for specified periods of time, could I create a loop that will return the sum delivery qty, per month from the new release date (NR_DATE) to the current date. Subquery would potentially look like the following (and then repeated for each required period)...

```
(select nvl(sum(dp.del_qty),0) from bds_dhead@sid_to_cdsuk dh, bds_dline@sid_to_cdsuk dp where dp.dhead_no = dh.dhead_no and dh.d_status = '9' and dp.article_no = '9'||nrb.p_catnr and trunc(dh.actshpdate) > trunc(sysdate - 30)) sum_CDS_delqty_30_days
```

I'm hoping I'm making some sense ... apologies if I'm not clear. I've only been writing SQL for a few months and have taught myself using existing, OLD, reports.

Thanks

FULL SCRIPT

```
select pd.part_no, 
   pd.catnr, 
   pd.prodtyp, 
   pd.packtyp, 
   pd.description, 
   ip.purchase_type, 
   nvl(pd.fod_idc, 'N'), 
   (select max(acp.qty_free_idc) 
      from oes_fod_match acp 
     where pd.part_no = acp.part_no 
       and acp.type = 'SUP' 
       and acp.cre_dat = (select max(acp1.cre_dat) 
                            from oes_fod_match acp1 
                           where acp.part_no = acp1.part_no 
                             and acp1.qty_free > 0 
                             and acp1.type = 'SUP')) qty_free_idc, 
   (select nvl(sum(pl.qty_onhand), 0) 
      from part_loc pl 
     where pl.part_no = pd.part_no 
       and pl.location_type = 'IN' 
       and pl.plant in ('A', 
           'T', 
           'L')) current_stock_at_comp, 
   (select nvl(sum(pl.qty_onhand), 0) 
      from part_loc pl 
     where pl.part_no = pd.part_no 
       and pl.location_type = 'IN' 
       and pl.plant in ('Z', 
           'V')) current_stock_cz_comp, 
   (select nvl(sum(pl.qty_onhand), 0) 
      from part_loc pl 
     where pl.part_no = pd.part_no 
       and pl.location_type = 'IN' 
       and pl.plant in ('W', 
           '2')) current_stock_uk_comp, 
   (select nvl(sum(pl.qty_onhand), 0) 
      from part_loc pl 
     where pl.part_no = pd.part_no 
       and pl.location_type = 'IN') total_stock_comp, 
   (select nvl(max(val_strg1), 0) 
      from sd_domainval dv 
     where dv.val_strg = pd.part_no) min_stock_lvl, 
   (select nvl(max(val_strg2), 0) 
      from sd_domainval dv 
     where dv.val_strg = pd.part_no) min_order_qty, 
   (select nvl(max(val_strg3), 'ND') 
      from sd_domainval dv 
     where dv.val_strg = pd.part_no) pref_assembly_plant, 
   (select nvl(max(pp.qty), 0) 
      from oes_purpos pp 
     where pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
       and pp.c_status != 'D' 
       and pp.datneu = (select max(pp1.datneu) 
                          from oes_purpos pp1 
                         where pp1.av_part_no = pp.av_part_no 
                           and pp1.c_status != 'D')) last_aw_po_qty, 
   (select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty - nvl(ps.del_qty, 0)), 0) 
      from oes_purpos pp, 
           oes_purseg ps 
     where ps.headnr = pp.headnr 
       and ps.posnr = pp.posnr 
       and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
       and ps.c_status not in ('9', 
           'D') 
       and ps.o_status not in ('D', 
           '9')) open_aw_po_qty, 
   (select nvl(sum(al.qty_onhand), 0) 
      from bds_location@sid_to_cdsuk l, 
           bds_article_location@sid_to_cdsuk al 
     where al.article_no = '9' || nrb.p_catnr 
       and al.qty_onhand <> 0 
       and l.location_no = al.location_no 
       and l.location_no like '  1             DCMS%' 
       and l.location_class not in ('D', 
           'C')) onhand_CDS, 
   (select nvl(sum(st.qty_in_process), 0) 
      from BDS_ARTICLE_INVLEVEL_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st 
     where st.article_no = '9' || nrb.p_catnr) allocated_CDS, 
   (select nvl(sum(st.qty_in_process), 0) 
      from BDS_ARTICLE_INVLEVEL_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st 
     where st.article_no = '9' || nrb.p_catnr) allocated_CDS, 
   (select min(selection_relse_date) 
      from BDS_SELECTION_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st 
     where substr(selection_no, 2, 99) = pd.catnr) NR_DATE, 
   (select sum(ds.planqty - nvl(ds.delqty, 0)) 
      from oes_opos op, 
           oes_oposdelseg ds, 
           ncf_comppart nc, 
           oes_nrbom nb 
     where ds.ordnr = op.ordnr 
       and ds.posnr = op.posnr 
       and nc.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
       and nb.c_catnr = nc.catnr 
       and nb.c_prodtyp = nc.prodtyp 
       and nb.c_packtyp = nc.packtyp 
       and nb.c_vernr = nc.vernr 
       and op.catnr = nb.p_catnr 
       and op.prodtyp = nb.p_prodtyp 
       and op.packtyp = nb.p_packtyp 
       and op.vernr = nb.p_vernr 
       and ds.c_status not in ('9', 
           'D') 
       and op.ol_typ = 'XX') sum_open_xx_order, 
   (select nvl(sum(pl.qty_onhand), 0) 
      from ncf_comppart nc, 
           oes_nrbom nb, 
           part_description pd1, 
           part_loc pl 
     where nc.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
       and nb.c_catnr = nc.catnr 
       and nb.c_prodtyp = nc.prodtyp 
       and nb.c_packtyp = nc.packtyp 
       and nb.c_vernr = nc.vernr 
       and pd1.catnr = nb.p_catnr 
       and pd1.prodtyp = nb.p_prodtyp 
       and pd1.packtyp = nb.p_packtyp 
       and pd1.vernr = nb.p_vernr 
       and pl.part_no = pd1.part_no) onhand_avalon_fp, 
   (select unique sv.gps_planshpdate 
      from oes_delsegview sv, 
           oes_opos op, 
           oes_oposdelseg ds, 
           oes_nrbom nb, 
           ncf_comppart cp 
     where cp.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
       and nb.c_catnr = cp.catnr 
       and nb.c_prodtyp = cp.prodtyp 
       and nb.c_packtyp = cp.packtyp 
       and nb.c_vernr = cp.vernr 
       and sv.ordnr = ds.ordnr 
       and sv.posnr = ds.posnr 
       and sv.catnr = nb.p_catnr 
       and sv.prodtyp = nb.p_prodtyp 
       and sv.packtyp = nb.p_packtyp 
       and op.ordnr = ds.ordnr 
       and op.posnr = ds.posnr 
       and op.catnr = nb.p_catnr 
       and op.prodtyp = nb.p_prodtyp 
       and op.packtyp = nb.p_packtyp 
       and op.vernr = nb.p_vernr 
       and nb.active = 'Y' 
       and op.ol_typ in ('XX', 
           'CO') 
       and sv.gps_planshpdate = (select max(sv1.gps_planshpdate) 
                                   from oes_delsegview sv1, 
                                        oes_opos op1, 
                                        oes_oposdelseg ds1, 
                                        oes_nrbom nb1, 
                                        ncf_comppart cp1 
                                  where cp1.item_part_no = cp.item_part_no 
                                    and nb1.c_catnr = cp1.catnr 
                                    and nb1.c_prodtyp = cp1.prodtyp 
                                    and nb1.c_packtyp = cp1.packtyp 
                                    and nb1.c_vernr = cp1.vernr 
                                    and sv1.ordnr = ds1.ordnr 
                                    and sv1.posnr = ds1.posnr 
                                    and sv1.catnr = nb1.p_catnr 
                                    and sv1.prodtyp = nb1.p_prodtyp 
                                    and sv1.packtyp = nb1.p_packtyp 
                                    and op1.ordnr = ds1.ordnr 
                                    and op1.posnr = ds1.posnr 
                                    and op1.catnr = nb1.p_catnr 
                                    and op1.prodtyp = nb1.p_prodtyp 
                                    and op1.packtyp = nb1.p_packtyp 
                                    and op1.vernr = nb1.p_vernr 
                                    and nb1.active = 'Y' 
                                    and sv1.ord_o_status = '9' 
                                    and op1.ol_typ in ('XX', 
                                        'CO'))) last_ship_date_manufacturing, 
   (select unique nvl(max(sv.delqty), 0) 
      from oes_delsegview sv, 
           oes_opos op, 
           oes_oposdelseg ds, 
           oes_nrbom nb, 
           ncf_comppart cp 
     where cp.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
       and nb.c_catnr = cp.catnr 
       and nb.c_prodtyp = cp.prodtyp 
       and nb.c_packtyp = cp.packtyp 
       and nb.c_vernr = cp.vernr 
       and sv.ordnr = ds.ordnr 
       and sv.posnr = ds.posnr 
       and sv.catnr = nb.p_catnr 
       and sv.prodtyp = nb.p_prodtyp 
       and sv.packtyp = nb.p_packtyp 
       and op.ordnr = ds.ordnr 
       and op.posnr = ds.posnr 
       and op.catnr = nb.p_catnr 
       and op.prodtyp = nb.p_prodtyp 
       and op.packtyp = nb.p_packtyp 
       and op.vernr = nb.p_vernr 
       and nb.active = 'Y' 
       and op.ol_typ in ('XX', 
           'CO') 
       and sv.gps_planshpdate = (select max(sv1.gps_planshpdate) 
                                   from oes_delsegview sv1, 
                                        oes_opos op1, 
                                        oes_oposdelseg ds1, 
                                        oes_nrbom nb1, 
                                        ncf_comppart cp1 
                                  where cp1.item_part_no = cp.item_part_no 
                                    and nb1.c_catnr = cp1.catnr 
                                    and nb1.c_prodtyp = cp1.prodtyp 
                                    and nb1.c_packtyp = cp1.packtyp 
                                    and nb1.c_vernr = cp1.vernr 
                                    and sv1.ordnr = ds1.ordnr 
                                    and sv1.posnr = ds1.posnr 
                                    and sv1.catnr = nb1.p_catnr 
                                    and sv1.prodtyp = nb1.p_prodtyp 
                                    and sv1.packtyp = nb1.p_packtyp 
                                    and op1.ordnr = ds1.ordnr 
                                    and op1.posnr = ds1.posnr 
                                    and op1.catnr = nb1.p_catnr 
                                    and op1.prodtyp = nb1.p_prodtyp 
                                    and op1.packtyp = nb1.p_packtyp 
                                    and op1.vernr = nb1.p_vernr 
                                    and nb1.active = 'Y' 
                                    and sv1.ord_o_status = '9' 
                                    and op1.ol_typ in ('XX', 
                                        'CO'))) last_ship_qty_manufacturing, 
   case when case when (select max(psd.conf_date) 
                          from oes_purseg psd, 
                               OES_PURSEGVIEW psv 
                         where psv.headnr = psd.headnr 
                           and psv.posnr = psd.posnr 
                           and psv.segnr = psd.segnr 
                           and psv.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
                           and psv.ps_o_status in ('1', '2', '7') 
                           and psv.ps_c_status not in ('D', '9')) is null then (select max(psd.requ_date)                                                                                       from oes_purseg psd, 
                                                                                       OES_PURSEGVIEW psv 
                                                                                 where psv.headnr = psd.headnr 
                                                                                   and psv.posnr = psd.posnr 
                                                                                   and psv.segnr = psd.segnr 
                                                                                   and psv.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
                                                                                   and psv.ps_o_status in ('0', '1', '2', '7') 
                                                                                   and psv.ps_c_status not in ('D', '9')) 
                  else (select max(psd.conf_date) 
                          from oes_purseg psd, 
                               OES_PURSEGVIEW psv 
                         where psv.headnr = psd.headnr 
                           and psv.posnr = psd.posnr 
                           and psv.segnr = psd.segnr 
                           and psv.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
                           and psv.ps_o_status in ('1', '2', '7') 
                           and psv.ps_c_status not in ('D', '9')) end is null then (select max(ps1.del_date) 
                                                                                      from oes_purseg ps1 
                                                                                     where ps1.headnr || ps1.posnr || ps1.segnr = (select rq.pur_headnr || rq.pur_posnr || rq.pur_segnr 
                                                                                                                                     from oes_requisition rq 
                                                                                                                                    where rq.seqnr = (select fm.req_seqnr 
                                                                                                                                                        from oes_fod_match fm 
                                                                                                                                                       where fm.part_no = pd.part_no 
                                                                                                                                                         and fm.qty_free_idc = 'Y' 
                                                                                                                                                         and fm.cre_dat = (select max(fM1.cre_dat) 
                                                                                                                                                                             from oes_fod_match fm1 
                                                                                                                                                                            where fm.part_no = fm1.part_no 
                                                                                                                                                                              and fm1.qty_free_idc = 'Y')))) 
        else case when (select max(psd.conf_date) 
                          from oes_purseg psd, 
                               OES_PURSEGVIEW psv 
                         where psv.headnr = psd.headnr 
                           and psv.posnr = psd.posnr 
                           and psv.segnr = psd.segnr 
                           and psv.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
                           and psv.ps_o_status in ('1', '2', '7') 
                           and psv.ps_c_status not in ('D', '9')) is null then (select max(psd.requ_date) 
                                                                                  from oes_purseg psd, 
                                                                                       OES_PURSEGVIEW psv 
                                                                                 where psv.headnr = psd.headnr 
                                                                                   and psv.posnr = psd.posnr 
                                                                                   and psv.segnr = psd.segnr 
                                                                                   and psv.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
                                                                                   and psv.ps_o_status in ('1', '2', '7') 
                                                                                   and psv.ps_c_status not in ('D', '9')) 
                  else (select /*+ ORDERED */ max(psd.conf_date) 
                          from oes_purseg psd, 
                               OES_PURSEGVIEW psv 
                         where psv.headnr = psd.headnr 
                           and psv.posnr = psd.posnr 
                           and psv.segnr = psd.segnr 
                           and psv.av_part_no = pd.part_no 
                           and psv.ps_o_status in ('1', '2', '7') 
                           and psv.ps_c_status not in ('D', '9')) end end ACP_start_date, 
   (select max(acp2.cre_dat) 
      from oes_fod_match acp2 
     where pd.part_no = acp2.part_no 
       and acp2.type = 'SUP' 
       and acp2.cre_usr = 'SOX9347') ACP_migration_date, 
   (select round(nvl(avg(dp.del_qty), 0)) 
      from bds_dhead@sid_to_cdsuk dh, 
           bds_dline@sid_to_cdsuk dp 
     where dp.dhead_no = dh.dhead_no 
       and dh.d_status = '9' 
       and dp.article_no = '9' || nrb.p_catnr 
       and dh.actshpdate > sysdate - 365) * 90 avg_CDS_delqty_last_2_mths, 
   nrb.p_catnr used_in_catnr 
  FROM part_description pd 
   INNER JOIN inventory_purchase ip 
      ON ip.part_no = pd.part_no 
   INNER JOIN scm_prodtyp pt 
      ON pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp 
   INNER JOIN oes_fod_match acp 
      ON acp.part_no = pd.part_no 
   INNER JOIN part_description pd3 
      ON pd3.part_no = pd.part_no 
   INNER JOIN NCF_COMPPART ncf 
      ON ncf.item_part_no = pd3.part_no 
   INNER JOIN oes_nrbom nrb 
      ON ncf.catnr = nrb.c_catnr 
         AND ncf.prodtyp = nrb.c_prodtyp 
         AND ncf.packtyp = nrb.c_packtyp 
         AND ncf.vernr = nrb.c_vernr 
 WHERE pd.cunr in ('649830', 'W30000') 
   and pd.catnr = '2EDVD0017' 
   and pd.fod_idc = 'Y' 
   and pt.prodgrp = 'AW'
```

Comment: Maybe you should put your script into SQL file and make it parameterized  and call N-times from master script in SQL*Plus passing new numbers. It is not loop but at least you don't need to copy/paste entire query.

Comment: You really want a fixed 91-day period, not three calendar months? Your periods will be different every year as you lose a day (or two in a leap year). A simpler example with sample data and required output would make it easier to understand and help you.

Comment: @SMORF when you have finished with this question please tick one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble deciding where to start, but I decided on this: JOINS

I seems to me, that if you try to apply ANSI join syntax that you have a table in your query with NO JOIN CONDITIONS and hence you may have a Cartesian product in effect which will just multiply the number of result rows.

i.e. in attempting to move from your original:

```
FROM part_description pd
   , inventory_purchase ip
   , scm_prodtyp pt
   , oes_fod_match acp
   , NCF_COMPPART ncf
   , part_description pd3
   , oes_nrbom nrb
WHERE ip.part_no = pd.part_no
      AND pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp
      AND pt.prodgrp = 'AW'
      AND pd.cunr IN ('649830', 'W30000')
      AND pd.catnr IN ('BBCDVD3285', 'BBCDVD3297', 'BBCDVD2816', '2EDVD0146', 'BBCDVD1020', 'BBCDVD2687', 'BBCDVD1106')
      AND pd.fod_idc = 'Y'
      AND ncf.item_part_no = pd3.part_no
      AND ncf.catnr = nrb.c_catnr
      AND ncf.prodtyp = nrb.c_prodtyp
      AND ncf.packtyp = nrb.c_packtyp
      AND ncf.vernr = nrb.c_vernr
      AND pd3.part_no = pd.part_no
```

to a variant using explict join syntax:

```
FROM part_description pd
INNER JOIN inventory_purchase ip ON ip.part_no = pd.part_no
INNER JOIN scm_prodtyp pt        ON pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp
                                     AND pt.prodgrp = 'AW'

CROSS JOIN oes_fod_match acp --<< NO join conditions given

INNER JOIN part_description pd3 ON pd3.part_no = pd.part_no
INNER JOIN NCF_COMPPART ncf     ON ncf.item_part_no = pd3.part_no

INNER JOIN oes_nrbom nrb ON ncf.catnr = nrb.c_catnr
                                   AND ncf.prodtyp = nrb.c_prodtyp
                                   AND ncf.packtyp = nrb.c_packtyp
                                   AND ncf.vernr = nrb.c_vernr

WHERE  pd.cunr IN ('649830', 'W30000')
      AND pd.catnr IN ('BBCDVD3285', 'BBCDVD3297', 'BBCDVD2816', '2EDVD0146', 'BBCDVD1020', 'BBCDVD2687', 'BBCDVD1106')
      AND pd.fod_idc = 'Y'
```

There is no specified join conditions for table: `oes_fod_match` (acp)

This will most probably be having **a large adverse effect on performance** of this query and which is perhaps why you use `SELECT UNIQUE` at the outset. "SELECT UNIQUE" will also make it slower by the way. Then multiply all of this by running 63 correlated subqueries, on many unnecessary rows. Wow! AND you want to add more subqueries.

Please stop for a moment and reconsider just the joins. I may be wrong, and I hope for your sake that I am, but please make sure `oes_fod_match` is joined correctly before adding anything.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the advice. You are correct; I was missing the acp join (acp.part_no = pd.part_no). Report now running MUCH quicker !!!

Comment: It is time for you to adopt explict join syntax, it is impossible to create an accidental Cartesian product that way. Replace "cross join" with "inner join" and follow that by "ON acp.part_no = pd.part_no". Then you have a valid set of joins and a much easier where clause to maintain. Really, please stop using "the ancient way of joining" (through the where clause).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the large number of "correlated subqueries" (63 I believe):

These are usually not an efficient way to query, and often they can be replaced by more efficient methods. I believe this is the situation here.

Here is an example for 6 of those subqueries (from the original unedited question):

```
   (select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty),0) from oes_purpos pp, oes_purseg ps where ps.headnr = pp.headnr and ps.posnr = pp.posnr and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no and ps.c_status != 'D' and ps.requ_date > sysdate - 90) sum_aw_po_qty_3_mths, 
   (select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty),0) from oes_purpos pp, oes_purseg ps where ps.headnr = pp.headnr and ps.posnr = pp.posnr and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no and ps.c_status != 'D' and ps.requ_date > sysdate - 180) sum_aw_po_qty_6_mths, 
   (select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty),0) from oes_purpos pp, oes_purseg ps where ps.headnr = pp.headnr and ps.posnr = pp.posnr and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no and ps.c_status != 'D' and ps.requ_date > sysdate - 270) sum_aw_po_qty_9_mths, 
   (select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty),0) from oes_purpos pp, oes_purseg ps where ps.headnr = pp.headnr and ps.posnr = pp.posnr and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no and ps.c_status != 'D' and ps.requ_date > sysdate - 365) sum_aw_po_qty_12_mths, 
   (select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty),0) from oes_purpos pp, oes_purseg ps where ps.headnr = pp.headnr and ps.posnr = pp.posnr and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no and ps.c_status != 'D' and ps.requ_date > sysdate - 540) sum_aw_po_qty_18_mths, 
   (select nvl(sum(ps.requ_qty),0) from oes_purpos pp, oes_purseg ps where ps.headnr = pp.headnr and ps.posnr = pp.posnr and pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no and ps.c_status != 'D' and ps.requ_date > sysdate - 730) sum_aw_po_qty_24_mths,
```

which I believe can be replaced by a more efficient single "derived table" like this:

```
...
FROM part_description pd
INNER JOIN (
            select
                  pp.av_part_no
                , SUM(case when ps.requ_date > TRUNC(sysdate) - 90   then requ_qty else 0 end)  sum_aw_po_qty_3_mths
                , SUM(case when ps.requ_date > TRUNC(sysdate) - 180  then requ_qty else 0 end)  sum_aw_po_qty_6_mths
                , SUM(case when ps.requ_date > TRUNC(sysdate) - 270  then requ_qty else 0 end)  sum_aw_po_qty_9_mths
                , SUM(case when ps.requ_date > TRUNC(sysdate) - 365  then requ_qty else 0 end)  sum_aw_po_qty_12_mths
                , SUM(case when ps.requ_date > TRUNC(sysdate) - 540  then requ_qty else 0 end)  sum_aw_po_qty_18_mths
                , SUM(requ_qty)                                                                 sum_aw_po_qty_24_mths
            from oes_purpos pp
            inner join oes_purseg ps ON  ps.headnr = pp.headnr and ps.posnr = pp.posnr
            where ps.c_status != 'D' and ps.requ_date > TRUNC(sysdate) - 730
            group by
                  pp.av_part_no
           ) pp on pp.av_part_no = pd.part_no
```

Instead of joining, scanning and filtering tables `oes_purpos pp, oes_purseg ps` 6 times, we do it once.

This same logic can be applied to several other (probably all) of the original 63 subqueries

---

by the way, you should use TRUNC(sysdate) so that the time component of sysdate is ignored (i.e. all date comparisons use midnight)